# Keras: batch training for multiple large datasets

Tags: deep-learning, keras

this question regards the common problem of training on multiple large files in Keras which are jointly too large to fit on GPU memory. 
I am using Keras 1.0.5 and I would like a solution that does not require 1.0.6. 
One way to do this was described by fchollet
[here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/107) and
[here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/68):

```
# Create generator that yields (current features X, current labels y)
def BatchGenerator(files):
    for file in files:
        current_data = pickle.load(open("file", "rb"))
        X_train = current_data[:,:-1]
        y_train = current_data[:,-1]
        yield (X_train, y_train)

# train model on each dataset
for epoch in range(n_epochs):
    for (X_train, y_train) in BatchGenerator(files):
        model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 32, nb_epoch = 1)
```

However I fear that the state of the model is not saved, rather that the model is reinitialized not only between epochs but also between datasets. Each "Epoch 1/1" represents training on a different dataset below:

~~~~~ Epoch 0 ~~~~~~

Epoch 1/1
295806/295806 [==============================] - 13s - loss: 15.7517
Epoch 1/1
407890/407890 [==============================] - 19s - loss: 15.8036
Epoch 1/1
383188/383188 [==============================] - 19s - loss: 15.8130
~~~~~ Epoch 1 ~~~~~~

Epoch 1/1
295806/295806 [==============================] - 14s - loss: 15.7517
Epoch 1/1
407890/407890 [==============================] - 20s - loss: 15.8036
Epoch 1/1
383188/383188 [==============================] - 15s - loss: 15.8130

I am aware that one can use model.fit_generator but as the method above was repeatedly suggested as a way of batch training I would like to know what I am doing wrong.

Thanks for your help,

Max

Comment: Have you tried to run your experiment on CPU in small batches by breaking your large files into smaller chunks?

Comment: pretty sure you need to use fit_generator, see https://keras.io/models/sequential/

Answer (score 8):

It has been a while since I faced that problem but I remember that I used
[Kera's functionality to provide data through Python generators](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#fit_generator), i.e. `model = Sequential(); model.fit_generator(...)`.

An exemplary code snippet (should be self-explanatory)

```
def generate_batches(files, batch_size):
   counter = 0
   while True:
     fname = files[counter]
     print(fname)
     counter = (counter + 1) % len(files)
     data_bundle = pickle.load(open(fname, "rb"))
     X_train = data_bundle[0].astype(np.float32)
     y_train = data_bundle[1].astype(np.float32)
     y_train = y_train.flatten()
     for cbatch in range(0, X_train.shape[0], batch_size):
         yield (X_train[cbatch:(cbatch + batch_size),:,:], y_train[cbatch:(cbatch + batch_size)])

model = Sequential()
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])

train_files = [train_bundle_loc + "bundle_" + cb.__str__() for cb in range(nb_train_bundles)]
gen = generate_batches(files=train_files, batch_size=batch_size)
history = model.fit_generator(gen, samples_per_epoch=samples_per_epoch, nb_epoch=num_epoch,verbose=1, class_weight=class_weights)
```

Comment: How would this be handled if the training data is in one file? I am able to load it up, but can't make 3 layers even due to resource errors.

Comment: just split it into several files, or is that not possible?

Comment: Hi @tenticon , I have a query with your last code. Does it train by each batch num_epochs or train overall all batches in one epoch then go for second one?

Comment: make sure the .py file is in a directory accessible by python.Put it in the same directory where your notebook is stored.

Comment: _fit_generator_ is deprecated in version **2.6.0+** so you can use only _model.fit_.
Be aware that _samples per epoch_ and _nb-epoch_ variables are not available anymore. 
[Source](https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/)