# How do I use "reduceLROnplateau" callback method with "train_on_batch" in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, artificial-intelligence

because I have a big dataset I should use `train_on_batch` instead of `model.fit` and I want to use `reduceLROnplateau` callback with it.What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use train_on_batch just because your data set is large. You can use model.fit. What you need to do is create a generator that feeds  the data to model.fit in batches. Then in model.fit you can use the reduceLROn plateau callback. If you are dealing with images you can use the ImaageDataGenerator to produce the batches. Documentation is [here.](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/), In the general case you have to create a python generator that will produce the batches of data. See the answer to a similar question [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38805375/keras-batch-training-for-multiple-large-datasets) on how to create a generator.

Comment: thanks but I should normalize the data before use it(and because normalizing make data bigger and I don't have enough RAM) I should normalize it and then train with it. what should I do?

Comment: In the generator you will specify the batch size. This controls how much memory you use., I do not know what kind of data you have but it is always best to normalize numerical data so all values are between 0 and 1. Again do this within the generator