# How do I load a 14,000 image data-set into a variable without running out of memory?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to make a function to load a large image data-set of 14,000 images into a variable but I'm running into memory (RAM) issues.

What I'm trying to make is something like a `cifar100.load_data` function but it's not working out for me.

The function I defined looks like this:

```py
    def load_data():
        trn_x_names=os.listdir('data/train_x')
        trn_y_names=os.listdir('data/train_y')
    
        trn_x_list=[] 
        trn_y_list=[]
    
        for image in trn_x_names[0:]:
            img=cv2.imread('data/train_x/%s'%image)
            img=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            trn_x_list.append(img)
        
        for image in trn_y_names[0:]:
            img=cv2.imread('data/train_y/%s'%image)
            img=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            trn_y_list.append(img)
        
        x_train= np.array(trn_x_list)
        y_train= np.array(trn_y_list)
        return x_train,y_train
```

I first load all the images one by one, adding them to corresponding lists and at the end changing those lists to a `numpy` array and assigning them to some variables and returning them. But on the way, I ran into RAM issues as it consumed 100 % of my RAM.

Comment: buy more RAM or rent it from a cloud computing provider

Comment: Set a batch_size, if you're using keras, then use model.fit_generator(...batch_size), if you're using torch or fastai, check thier docs for more info. Check my own ipynb file [here](https://github.com/Shashank-Shukla/Image_classificaation_CNN/blob/master/Student%20Notebook.ipynb). Go to Task-5. I didn't use cifar10, but it'll be similar to that

Comment: This is sort of an open question: if you need to have the data stored in a variable, then there's that: you can't escape it. If you can afford to reduce the image dimensions, that's a first step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read in your images in batches as opposed to loading the entire data set into memory. If you are using tensorflow use the ImageDataGenerator.flowfromdirectory. Documentation is [here.](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator) If your data is not organized into sub directories then you will need to create a python generator that reads in the data in batches. You can see how to build such a generator [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38805375/keras-batch-training-for-multiple-large-datasets). Set the batch size to a value say 30 that will not fill up your memory.