# Dealing with very large Memap file for training with tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

My numeric input data (df_input = np.load(memmap file)) to a neural network is a 350 GB memap numpy file with about 230 million rows and 150 columns (column 20 is the target). I am using tensorflow keras. Even though I am using data generators with batches (as shown below), its extremely slow run. Any feedback what I should do? I have number of epochs as 10,000, and after 4 hours, it went to 1/24863 mini batch of: Epoch 1/10000!!

Here is the data generator:

```
   class data_generator(Sequence):
'Generates data for Keras'
     def __init__(self, df_input, batch_size_gen, target_col_idx, input_cols_idx, 
     partition_idx, partition_set=None, gen_indices = False, shuffle=False):
        self.batch_size = batch_size_gen
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.partition_idx = partition_idx
        self.on_epoch_end()
        self.partition_set = partition_set
    
        self.gen_indices = gen_indices
        self.df_input = df_input
        self.input_cols_idx = input_cols_idx
        self.target_col_idx = target_col_idx

     def __len__(self):
       'Denotes the number of times file batches are retrieved and fed to ANN per epoch'
    #return int(np.floor(len(self.partition_idx)/ self.batch_size))
       return int(np.ceil(len(self.partition_idx)/ self.batch_size))

     def __getitem__(self, index):
       'Generate one batch of data by retrieving a batch of files'
    # Generate indexes of the batch
        indexes = self.indexes[index*self.batch_size:(index+1)*self.batch_size]
    # Find list of batch files to process 
        current_batch_idx = [self.partition_idx[k] for k in indexes]
        current_batch = self.df_array[current_batch_idx,:]
        #print(current_batch)
    # Generate data
         X, y = self.Data_Generator(current_batch)
    
    return X, y
```

Here is the training & calibration data:

```
   batch_size_gen = 20000

    training_generator = data_generator(df_input, batch_size_gen, target_col_idx, 
    input_cols_idx,train_idx, partition_set = 'Training',gen_indices = True, shuffle=False)

    calibration_generator = data_generator(df_input, batch_size_gen, 
    target_col_idx,input_cols_idx,calibration_idx,partition_set = 'Calibration',gen_indices = 
    False)
```

And this is how I call the fit:

```
    hist = model.fit_generator(generator=training_generator,validation_data = 
    calibration_generator, epochs = n_epoch,use_multiprocessing=False, callbacks = [reduce, 
    earlystop,checkpointer, csv_logger])
```

*** Update: I saw from another StackOverflow post that to speed up the training process of large train data, I might need to divide my input data file into several or many other files and train each. However, I am not sure if that's what I need and how to do it tailor to my situation of having only one large datasets: [Keras: batch training for multiple large datasets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38805375/keras-batch-training-for-multiple-large-datasets)

Comment: Reduce the batch size, 20K is just a crazy value.

Comment: It did not help, actually it made it run longer

Comment: So are you saying that a single step takes more than 4 hours? With what batch size?

Comment: Run your model and calculate how many samples per second you need to consume (for example if your model runs at 10% GPU utilization and consumes 10 samples/sec, you need to generate 100 samples/sec to fully utilize your hardware). Now take your model out of the equation and verify you can simply iterate over your data loader, consuming (and discarding) at least 100 samples/sec. Optimize data loading separately from your model, else it becomes too complicated to deal with.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy i tried with batch size of 500 instead of 20,000 and it went to 800/994500 of epoch 1/10000 in 4 hours. With B.S of 20k, it had gone to 1/24863 mini batch of: Epoch 1/10000

Comment: That sounds like its faster, not slower. What hardware are you using to train this?

Comment: It was a type, with 20k, it went to 34/24863, that's why i said slower. Running it on High Performance Computing with 1 nodes and 20 ppn

Comment: So no GPU? No wonder its so slow. You need to use GPUs.